# Unable to display angular variable value in a modal box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

`{{$scope.custdata[0].email_id}}` below is not working. I tried `{{$scope.email_id}}` and `{{email_id}`} etc in its place and none is working. I also tried to view debugger and no error is displayed. The below div is populated with list on page load and then when I click, `getCustomerData` method is called successfully and I can see the correct value being fetched in the controller. Not sure if its some timing issue and if it is, how to handle it. Need help. Thanks.

Here is the div -

```
<div class="images-div" ng-controller="getCustomer360Ctrl">
                   <ul ng-repeat="c in custdata">
                        <li><a ng-click="getCustomerData(c.member_id)"><img class="class="data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="../images/user.ico" alt="img" /></a><p class="c-inf">{{c.member_id}}</p></li>
                   </ul>
                   <div></div>
               </div>
```

Following is modal window code -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-p">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top: -122px;width: 479px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5>Customer 360 view</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div><img style="width: 150px; height:100px;" src="../images/user.ico" alt="img"/><p class=""> Unique id: 0019097<br>Gender: Female
</p></div>
            <div style="    float: right; width: 304px; height: 155px;margin-top: -152px;"><p>First Name:Jasmine<br> Last Name:  Thompson
</p>
                <p>Email Id:  {{$scope.custdata[0].email_id}}<br>Country: USA


                </p>
                <button type="button" style="margin-left: 162px;" class="btn btn-warning">Details in pdf </button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Here is the controller -

```
customerStat.controller('CustomerStatCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.custdata=[];
    $scope.emailid;
    $scope.getCustomerData = function(member_id){
        //alert("Cust ID::"+"select * from hive.dataxylo.`Customer_Unified` where  where member_id ="+member_id);

        $http.post('http://url/.json', {
            queryType:  "SQL",
            query: "select ......"
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

            $scope.custdata=data['rows'];
            $scope.emailid=$scope.custdata[0].email_id;

        }).error(function(err,data){
            alert("Error11::"+data);
        });
    }

})
```

Comment: You forget the `$` sign before `scope` in `<p>Email Id:  {{scope.custdata[0].email_id}}<br>Country: USA`

Comment: `$scope` is implicit in expressions `{{ }}`,  it should not be provided at all.

Comment: also, in general, if you are referring to items by their array position inside expressions, your data isn't refined enough

Comment: Even {{custdata[0].email_id}} is not working. Agree with data refinement, did communicate the same to the repective guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal div should be inside `<div class="images-div" ng-controller="CustomerStatCtrl">`.

```
    <div class="images-div" ng-controller="CustomerStatCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="c in custdata">
    <li><a ng-click="getCustomerData(c.member_id)"><img class="class="data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="../images/user.ico" alt="img" /></a><p class="c-inf">{{c.member_id}}</p></li>
</ul>
<div></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-p">
        <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top: -122px;width: 479px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5>Customer 360 view</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div><img style="width: 150px; height:100px;" src="../images/user.ico" alt="img"/><p class=""> Unique id: 0019097<br>Gender: Female
                </p></div>
                <div style="    float: right; width: 304px; height: 155px;margin-top: -152px;"><p>First Name:Jasmine<br> Last Name:  Thompson
                </p>
                    <p>Email Id:  {{custdata[0].email_id}}<br>Country: USA


                    </p>
                    <button type="button" style="margin-left: 162px;" class="btn btn-warning">Details in pdf </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Could you please explain the reason behind please.

Comment: Email ID is getting displayed on the modal now, but its not getting refreshed. Every time, it displays the same data. Also, if I tried with {{emailid}}, it doesn't work. Just wondering why??

Comment: This is because you are always showing the first element of array custdata[0]

Comment: The reason behind modal not showing email was that the modal was not in controllers scope. Inside modal you didn't have access to controller's scope variable. Moving it inside the div in which you declared ng-controller, makes the modal access controller scope.

Comment: Mr. Godzina answered this question first and then you edited your answer. That's not a nice way varun.

Comment: My answer is different from Mr. Godzina's answer. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You´r assigning the wrong controller name to ng-controller.
Replace the value of  ng-controller to the name of the controller you defined: ng-controller="**CustomerStatCtrl as CustomerCtrl**"

Its best practice to use an alias with the **as** keyword. Inside the Div $scope variables can be reached like this:

> {{ **CustomerCtrl**.custdata[i] }} or {{ **CustomerCtrl**.emailid }}

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use $scope or scope in html use this 
`{{custdata[0].email_id}}`